# strange encoding issue in chrome - "i" is shown wrong

Tags: google-chrome, encoding, character-encoding

[image]

I have this issue sometimes, (sometimes it works) in turkish pages in chrome. in Firefox it works well. The page is deployed on multiple servers. What can this be? may be some font is missing in some servers?

any help is appreciated much

Answer (score 1):

The font that your Chrome uses might not have a glyph for Turkish "i" letter. Try to launch Chrome with parameter "--user-data-dir=/dev/null" and open one of problematic pages.

If that does not help and your Windows version is not Turkish one, you probably should install respective fonts.